# Error java code eclipse SQL Error: 972, SQLState: 42000 ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting error 
SQL Error: 972, SQLState: 42000
ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Below is my code:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.example.demo.dao.Pharmacyservice;
import com.example.demo.model.Pharmacy;

@SpringBootApplication

public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    Pharmacyservice pharmacyservice;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        getPharmacy();
    }

    private void getPharmacy() {        
        /*Pharmacy ph = new Pharmacy();*/       
        /*ph.setPharmacyIdentifier(2);*/
        Iterable<Pharmacyphs=new ArrayList<>();
        /*Optional <Pharmacy> phs =Optional.of(ph);*/

        phs = pharmacyservice.getPharmacy(2);
        System.out.println(phs);
    }
}
```

-

```
package com.example.demo.dao;

import java.util.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.model.Pharmacy;

@Service
public class Pharmacyservice {
    @Autowired
    PharmacyImpl pharmacyImpl;
    public Iterable<Pharmacy> getPharmacy(Integer id) {
        return pharmacyImpl.findAll();

    }


}

public interface PharmacyImpl extends CrudRepository<Pharmacy, Integer> {

}

@Component
@Entity
@Table(name="PHARMACY",schema="cf_7a96116e_afac_4e08_b6d8_2492a89d5652")
public class Pharmacy {

    @Id
    @Column(name="PHARMACY_IDENTITY")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer pharmacyIdentifier;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_ID")
    private String pharmacyId;

    @Column(name="DAT_SRC_ID")
    private String dataSourceId;

    @Column(name="SRC_PHMCY_ID")
    private String sourcePharmacyId;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_CORP_ID")
    private String pharmacyCorpId;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_NM")
    private String pharmacyName;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_ADDR_LINE1_TX")
    private String addressLine1Text;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_ADDR_LINE2_TX")
    private String addressLine2Text;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_ADDR_LINE3_TX")
    private String addressLine3Text;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_CITY_TX")
    private String pharmacyCityText;

    @Column(name="CNTY_TX")
    private String countyText;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_ST_CD")
    private String pharmacyStateCode;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_ZIP_CD")
    private String pharmacyZipCode;

    @Column(name="PHONE_NB")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name="BILL_FAX_NB")
    private String billFaxNumber;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_RGN_CD")
    private String pharmacyRegionCode;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_SRVC_TYP")
    private String pharmcyServiceType;

    @Column(name="DBA_NM")
    private String dbaName;

    @Column(name="DEA_NB")
    private String deaNumber;

    @Column(name="FAX_NB")
    private String faxNumber;

    @Column(name="LOCKBOX_NB")
    private String lockBoxNumber;

    @Column(name="NABP_NB")
    private String nabpNumber;

    @Column(name="NPI_NB")
    private String npiNumber;

    @Column(name="IST_LIC_NB")
    private String istLICNumber;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_STORE_NB")
    private Integer pharmacyStoreNumber;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_MGR_NM")
    private String pharmacyMgrName;

    @Column(name="RPH_IN_CHRG_ID")
    private String rphInchargeId;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_MEDB_LEGL_NM")
    private String pharmacyMedbLegalName;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_MEDB_TAX_ID")
    private String pharmacyMedbTaxId;

    @Column(name="RTRN_ALLW_IN")
    private String rtrnAllowIn;

    @Column(name="IS_CLOS_IN")
    private String isCloseIn;

    @Column(name="PHMCY_ACTV_IN")
    private String pharmacyActiveIn;

    @Column(name="CURR_REC_IN")
    private String currentRecIn;

}
```

SQL query being generated:
    select
        pharmacy0_.PHARMACY_IDENTITY as PHARMACY1_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_ADDR_LINE1_TX as PHMCY_AD2_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_ADDR_LINE2_TX as PHMCY_AD3_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_ADDR_LINE3_TX as PHMCY_AD4_14_,
        pharmacy0_.BILL_FAX_NB as BILL_FAX5_14_,
        pharmacy0_.CNTY_TX as CNTY_TX6_14_,
        pharmacy0_.CURR_REC_IN as CURR_REC7_14_,
        pharmacy0_.DAT_SRC_ID as DAT_SRC_8_14_,
        pharmacy0_.DBA_NM as DBA_NM9_14_,
        pharmacy0_.DEA_NB as DEA_NB10_14_,
        pharmacy0_.FAX_NB as FAX_NB11_14_,
        pharmacy0_.IS_CLOS_IN as IS_CLOS12_14_,
        pharmacy0_.LOCKBOX_NB as LOCKBOX13_14_,
        pharmacy0_.NABP_NB as NABP_NB14_14_,
        pharmacy0_.NPI_NB as NPI_NB15_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_ACTV_IN as PHMCY_A16_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_CITY_TX as PHMCY_C17_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_CORP_ID as PHMCY_C18_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_ID as PHMCY_I19_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_MEDB_LEGL_NM as PHMCY_M20_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_MEDB_TAX_ID as PHMCY_M21_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_MGR_NM as PHMCY_M22_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_NM as PHMCY_N23_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_RGN_CD as PHMCY_R24_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_ST_CD as PHMCY_S25_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_STORE_NB as PHMCY_S26_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_ZIP_CD as PHMCY_Z27_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHMCY_SRVC_TYP as PHMCY_S28_14_,
        pharmacy0_.PHONE_NB as PHONE_N29_14_,
        pharmacy0_.RPH_IN_CHRG_ID as RPH_IN_30_14_,
        pharmacy0_.RTRN_ALLW_IN as RTRN_AL31_14_,
        pharmacy0_.SRC_PHMCY_ID as SRC_PHM32_14_,
        pharmacy0_.ST_LIC_NB as ST_LIC_33_14_ 
    from
        cf_bfd29943_914a_4174_9ba1_42146cdbf376PHARMACY pharmacy0_ 
    where
        pharmacy0_.PHARMACY_IDENTITY=?

I can't understand where is I am doing things wrong  !! Please help

Comment: Can you please post your stacktrace as well?

Comment: I am new to java so don't know about stack trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think is happening: you have a setup that tries to create a database schema on the first run, according to your @Entity classes.

You are using Oracle (ORA exception) where max schema name length is 30 bytes (in Oracle 12.1 and below), and your schema name `cf_7a96116e_afac_4e08_b6d8_2492a89d5652` is 39 characters, so it's too long. Change your schema name and try again.

Comment: I was using an earlier version of jdbc connector jar. I downloaded the newest version & this schema name  got removed from query.